# How to clear a form within an angular app that appears on click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have seen several tutorials on how to clear angular (version 1.4.0) forms, however.. none of them seem to work in my case. I am puzzled. The following form is `display: none;` to begin with, but comes into existence when the 'Add' button is clicked.

```
<div id="..." class="displayNone ...">
        <form class="..." name="addFooForm">
            <div class="...">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Foos</label>
                            <input type="text" class="..." id="..." ng-model="foo.value">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="...">
                ...
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="..." ng-click="resetAddFooForm()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And in my controller, I have the following.

```
$scope.resetAddFooForm = function () {

    // XXX:
    console.log('about to reset the form');

    $scope.foo = {};
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setValidity();
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setPristine();
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setUntouched();
};
```

But, although the `console.log` message is being displayed. The form field is not being cleared. I have have even tried doing it directly as follows.

```
$scope.resetAddFooForm = function () {

    // XXX:
    console.log('about to reset the form');

    $scope.fooVal = '';
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setValidity();
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setPristine();
    // $scope.addFooForm.$setUntouched();
};
```

.. with the above html modified as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Foos</label>
    <input type="text" class="..." id="foo" ng-model="fooVal">
</div>
```

But nothing seems to be working. Is it perhaps because the `$scope` is different due to the form being dynamically inserted? But then how do I tackle that?

I just want to be able to clear the fields (and also clear the angular properties like dirty/pristine, etc) of this dynamically generated form.

### Update:

---

I was able to send `this` from the html back to the controller, and then use it do what I wanted. So it appears that the problem may actually be to do with differing scopes.

```
<div class="...">
   ...
   <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="..." ng-click="resetAddFooForm(this)">
</div>
```

And then have this retrieved the controller.

```
$scope.resetAddFooForm = function (elem) {
    elem.foo = {};
    elem.$setValidity();
    elem.$setPristine();
    elem.$setUntouched();
};
```

Any hints? Why do I need to send `this`, when I should really be able to simply use `$scope`. Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 1):

Initially declare empty object on your controller

`$scope.foo = {}`

then try empty it on reset

Answer (score -1):

You can manually reset fields value.